# Preventing loading duplicates when lazy loading in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, lazy-loading, nosql

I am trying to lazy load items using Firebase V3. I have already [denormalized](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) my data, but I would like to take it a step further.

So far, I tried to filter out the data using the queries `.limitToLast()` as follows:

```
var limitLength = 20;
var orderNode   = "price";

firebase.database().ref(refPath).orderByChild(orderNode).limitToFirst(limitLength).on('value', function(snapshot) {
   //success: snapshot.val()
}, function(error){
   //error
});
```

The problem is, that when I increase the length to 40, Firebase will reload the first 20 items as well. This will obviously hurt my performance when the `limitLength` increases.

How can this be overcome? I.e. how can I only load the data that comes in the places 21...40?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell the query to *skip* the first 20 items. But you can tell it to *start at* a specific item. With that you can accomplish *almost* the same thing, the difference is how you implement it and a single overlapping item between consecutive query pairs.

```
var limitLength = 20;
var orderNode   = "price";
var latestKey, latestProp;

var location = firebase.database().ref(refPath);
var query = location.orderByChild(orderNode).limitToFirst(limitLength);
query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
       latestKey = child.key;
       latestProp = child.val()[orderNode];
   });
   query = location.orderByChild(orderNode).startAt(latestProp, latestKey).limitToFirst(limitLength+1);
}, function(error){
   //error
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Another thing though... is it possible to reverse the sorting of the .orderByChild()? Perhaps should be a separate question.

Comment: That is indeed a separate question. Don't post it though, but search: it's been asked and answered quite a few times already.

Comment: It was incredibly simple.. replace .limitToFirst with .limitToLast!

Comment: That will return the children from the other end of the list, but it won't reverse the order in which they're returned. I assume you did the reversing client-side then?

Comment: Yes that worked. However, using the code above, I am getting null every time I try to reload the list with .startAt(...). the latestProp and latestKey are correct, but the query still returns null. I have also updated limitLength with +20.